# list of item on top of each other

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, arrays, list

I used map function to display item in API but in print they have been printed on top of each other
They must be 4 items : [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apl1A.png)

how I can make padding for them

```
        <div>
          <div className="taskcolorback-div" />
          <button className="taskcolor-button" />
          <b className="tasktext-b">{item.ActivityType}</b>
          <button className="taskwhite-button" />
          <b className="b">5Hr</b>
          <img className="vector-icon" alt="" src="icons8-chevron-right-64.png" />
        </div>
```

the above code is in react and this is the css code I used class for each item to fix the position but in print it will print them top of each other

```css
.taskcolor-button,
  .taskcolorback-div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 151px;
    left: 464px;
    border-radius: 22.5px;
    background-color: #d2d3f8;
    width: 351.62px;
    height: 61px;
  }
  .taskcolor-button {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #5051f9;
    width: 178.24px;
  }
  .tasktext-b {
    position: absolute;
    top: 171px;
    left: 506px;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    width: 101px;
    height: 23px;
  }
  .taskwhite-button {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 161.84px;
    left: 687.61px;
    border-radius: 14px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(80, 81, 249, 0.16);
    width: 79.4px;
    height: 37.96px;
  }
  .b,
  .vector-icon {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .b {
    top: 171.33px;
    left: 705.44px;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    width: 42.13px;
    height: 21.69px;
  }
  .vector-icon {
    height: 2%;
    width: 0.90%;
    top: 15.8%;
    right: 58.26%;
    bottom: 82.44%;
    left: 41.21%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
```

this is the map function

```js
function Feed(props) {

    console.table(props.data);
    return (
      <>
        {
          props.data.map(item=> (
          <div>
          <div className="taskcolorback-div" />
          <button className="taskcolor-button" />
          <b className="tasktext-b">{item.ActivityType}</b>
          <button className="taskwhite-button" />
          <b className="b">5Hr</b>
          <img className="vector-icon" alt="" src="icons8-chevron-right-64.png" />
          </div>
          )) 
        }
  
      </>
    )
  }
```

Comment: If you create a functional, runnable snippet with properly formatted HTML and CSS it will be much easier to help you. Without a snippet, all I can tell you is that it's possibly `position: absolute` causing the items to stack on top of each other.

Comment: snippet for functional has been add